# How to trigger a pre-everything file copy in Android Studio gradle file

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project with a dependency on a 'library.aar' file produced by another project. The 'library.aar' file exists in a known relative directory and I'd like to copy it into my project's directory prior to ANY other processing by gradle.

I've tried a number of ways but none of them work because gradle does some kind of file check for the .aar VERY early on in the process. I need to copy the file into place prior to that process tripping and complaining the file doesn't exist.  Alternatively, I'm fine referencing it from the other location as well.

So does such an early hook exist in gradle?  And how do I trigger my copy task off of it?

Comment: is the other project that produces the dependency a gradle project?

Comment: Does end of the config phase, before any build tasks are execution, work for you?

Comment: My project folder structure includes "MyApp" at the top level and under that is "app" where my code is located. Parallel to "app" is a folder called "library" and in that folder are three files: build.gradle, library.iml, and library.aar (which I currently copy manually every time the library is built). I want to copy 'library.aar' into that folder from its source location prior to building.

Comment: The problem is no matter what I've tried so far, gradle always complains "library.aar specified for property 'bundle' does not exist".  This is of course because it looks for the library during dependency checking at the beginning. I believe that's prior to the config phase, no?

Comment: you should add your library project as a dependency to your app project. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies

Comment: Yep, it is. As outlined above.  I need to pull the current version prior to every build.

Comment: Why? if your lib project is added as a `project:` dependency in your app project, gradle will build the lib project first and will know where to find the lib jar to use in the app project. Why are you copying anything at all?

Comment: I can't mingle code & projects like that.  The library is a separate project from a separate company and all i get is their .aar file.  If you put that in a folder for your app project, Android Studio picks it up automatically and all is well.  Except you must update the file manually.  I'm just trying to remove the manual step by copying it from my "downloads" folder prior to building.  Seems trivial enough, but nope.

Comment: Here's the contents of the build.gradle file within my "library" folder as mentioned above.  configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('cgdvAndroid.aar'))

task aarCopy(type: Copy) {
    description = 'copying ' + project.name
    from "${projectDir}/../../../cgdv-lib/libs/android"
    into project.projectDir
    include(project.name + '.aar')
}

//beforeEvaluate {
//    preBuild.dependsOn{aarCopy}
//    aarCopy
//}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn aarCopy
}